# Añadir una restricción de columna para que un valor no sea menor al mínimo

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

¿Puedo añadir un check con una consulta sobre una columna en Oracle?

Tenemos una tabla ya creada, ahora nos piden añadir una restricción de salario: que el salario tiene que ser como mínimo del que menos cobre de los empleados.

Comment: No me queda claro que preguntas. Se un poco mas especifico.

Comment: Buenas, si perdona me explico muy mal y no se como explicarme en estos temas. Tenemos una tabla ya creada, ahora nos piden añadir una restriccion de salario siendo la restriccion que el salario tiene que ser como mínimo del que menos cobre de los empleados

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías tener una tabla dedicada al salario mínimo, de este modo te ahorras tener que leer cada vez todos los empleados buscando el que cobre menos. Además, el salario mínimo es información propia de una tabla específica que formaría parte de la política de la empresa.

Dicha tabla te serviría además para actualizar de forma automática el salario de todos los empleados cuando haya un aumento, o disminución (esperemos que esto no), del salario mínimo.

Sería algo más o menos así:

Teniendo las tablas:

- `tablaPoliticasEmpresa`
  con una columna llamada `salario_minimo` y otras

y

- `tablaEmpleados`
  con una columna llamada `salario` y otras ...

Puedes crear un [TRIGGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm) que se ejecute cada vez que haya una inserción o actualización en la `tablaEmpleados`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verificar_salario_minimo
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tablaEmpleados
      FOR EACH ROW
        DECLARE
          minimo tablaPoliticasEmpresa.salario_minimo%type;
          BEGIN
            SELECT salario_minimo
            INTO minimo
            FROM tablaPoliticasEmpresa;

            IF(:NEW.salario<minimo)THEN
              RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20250,'Estás introduciendo un salario inferior al salario mínimo');
            END IF;
END;
```